# Magento2 configurable product import quantity

Tags: magento, magento2

I have followed all instruction of import configurable products given in https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/3-steps-import-configurable-products-magento-2.html
but when i import configurable product quantity sets to 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question doesn't look like it's about programming, it might be better asked in a Magento forum

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2, the default configuration for Configurable Products would have to be changed** in order to import inventory as a value other than 0 with that extension (most likely). It's not recommended to change that configuration either, however, and here's why:

**Typical Example** - A Configurable Product (Shirt with 3 color variations) is included in a Store Catalog. Each of the simple products assigned to that Configurable (a red shirt, a blue shirt, and a green shirt) all have different inventory that is constantly changing, because some colors sell more than others and therefore, some of those Simple Products are restocked more frequently than others. Even though the 3 products are all are assigned to the same Configurable Product in this scenario, tracking inventory for the Configurable (as a sum of all the Simple Product's quantities) wouldn't be especially useful in Sales Reports or in Restocking the Store Inventory. Sometimes there are exceptions (usually with Virtual products) but for the most part, Magento store administrators will leave the default configuration as-is here because otherwise, the Configurable Product's quantity (which is really just the combined sum of the Simple Product's inventory) isn't a valuable metric to track in the majority of business cases.

**If there is a business case for tracking inventory at the Configurable level here**, however, then I highly recommend uRapidflow Pro by Unirgy. That extension has worked well for bulk imports/exports since Magento 1 and most other similar products have been especially buggy from Magento 2.1.5-2.2.x.